# UnitTest not compatible

Tags: c#, unit-testing, version, .net-6.0, compatibility

Tried to insert a UnitTest in my project, but VS is claiming, that .NET 6.0 is not compatible with .NET 6.0. This is the exact message:

> The project is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). The project supports the following: net6.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0).

Tried to create the UnitTest with .NET 7.0 but got the same result.
Anyone experienced something similar and got a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

> The project supports the following: `net6.0-windows7.0`

> Tried to create the UnitTest with .NET 7.0

`net6.0-windows7.0` means that your project target .NET 6 on Windows (not .NET 7). To reference such project in unit test one you need to match the target.

Open the `.csproj` file of the tested project and copy `TargetFramework(s)` and `RuntimeIdentifier(s)` props to the unit test one.

See also:

- [.NET runtime identifier (RID) Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#windows-rids)
- [MSBuild reference for .NET SDK projects: RuntimeIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#runtimeidentifier)

Comment: Thank you, i changed the target operating system at my UnitTest to Windows 7.0 and now it seems to work properly.